# 404 errors that look like strange SQL queries - how to block?

Tags: security, redirect, http-status-code-404

I have an E-commerce site (built on OpenCart 2.0.3.1).
Using an SEO pack plugin that keeps a list of 404 errors, so we can make redirects.
As of a couple of weeks ago, I keep seeing a LOT of 404s that don't even look like links:

- 999999.9 /**/uNiOn/**/aLl /**/sElEcT 0x393133353134353632312e39
- 999999.9 /**/uNiOn/**/aLl /**/sElEcT 0x393133353134353632312e39,0x393133353134353632322e39
- 999999.9 /**/uNiOn/**/aLl /**/sElEcT 0x393133353134353632312e39,0x393133353134353632322e39,0x393133353134353632332e39
- ...and so on, until it reaches:
- 999999.9" /**/uNiOn/**/aLl /**/sElEcT 0x393133353134353632312e39,0x393133353134353632322e39,0x393133353134353632332e39,0x393133353134353632342e39,0x393133353134353632352e39,0x393133353134353632362e39,0x393133353134353632372e39,0x393133353134353632382e39,0x393133353134353632392e39,0x39313335313435363231302e39,0x3931

This isn't happening once, but 30-50 times per example. Over 1600 lines of this mess in the latest 404s report.

Now, I know how to make redirects for "normal" broken links, but:

- a.) I have no clue how to even format this.
- b.) I'm concerned that this could be a brute-hacking attempt.

What would StackOverflow do?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with sw development, this is an admin / cyber security related stuff.

Comment: It's more of a redirects / mySQL question... the "cyber security" is a distant possibility.

But, what would be a more appropriate forum to move this to, then?

Comment: Wrong, this is a cyber attack and it should be your firewall / webserver level security module that deals with it, not your application's redirect module. Mysql has nothing to do with this at all. See https://serverfault.com/questions/541401/mysql-injection-attacks-random-urls-causing-errors

Answer (score 2):

TomJones999 - 
As is mentioned in the comments (sort of), this is a security issue for you. The reason for so many URL requests is because it is likely a script that is rifling through many URL requests which have SQL in them and the script / hacker is attempting to either do a reconnaissance and find if your site / pages are susceptible to an SQL Injection attack, or, since they likely already know what E-Commerce Site (AND VERSION) you are using, they could be intending to exploit a known vulnerability with this SQL Injection attempt and achieve some nefarious result (DB access, Data Dump, etc).

A few things I would do:

- Make sure your OpenCart is up to date and has all the latest patches applied
- If it is up to date, it might be worth bringing up in the forums or to an OpenCart Moderator in case the attacker is going after a weakness he found but that OpenCart has not pushed a patch for yet.
- Immediately, you can try to ban the attacker's IP address, but it is likely that they are going to use several different IP addresses and rotate through them. I might suggest looking into either ModSecurity or fail2ban ( https://www.fail2ban.org/ ). Fail2Ban can be a great add on for security in these situations because there are several ways for it to 'dynamically' thwart this attack attempt.

  - The excessive 404 errors in a short time span can be observed by fail2ban and fail2ban can then ban the client that is causing all of them
  - Also, there is a [fail2ban filter for detecting attempted SQL injections](https://github.com/gofullthrottle/fail2ban-apache-sqlinject) and consequently banning the users. For example, I quickly searched and found this fail2ban filter with a few adjustments/improvements/fixes to the Regular Expression that detects the SQL injection.

I would not concern yourself at all with "how to format" that error log heh...

With regards to your code (or the code in OpenCart), what you want to be sure of is that all user submitted data is *sanitized* (such as data sent to your server as a GET parameter as in your case).

Also, if you feel uneasy about the attempted hack, it might be worth watching the feed provided on the haveibeenpwned website because data resulting from exploits targeted at databases very commonly tend to end up on sites like pastebin etc and haveibeenpwned will try to parse some of the data and identify these hacks so that you or your users can at least become aware and take appropriate measures.

Best of luck.